# Laravel custom validation for confirm password

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5

I have to do the back end validation for confirm password. I write my validator as

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'first_name' => 'required',
    'last_name' => 'required',
    'email' => 'email|required',
    'password' => 'required',
    'confirm_password' => 'required',
    'tnc' => 'required'
]);
```

now the confirm password must be same as the password field. Can we do it with laravel validator?

Comment: Try simply to add `|confirmed` like this `'confirm_password' => 'required|confirmed'` !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'password'  =>  'required|min:6|confirmed',
'confirm_password'  =>  'required|min:6|confirmed',
```

try this

Comment: This is right, exept, you don't need to confirme twice.  
'confirm_password' rule can be removed since `confirmed` will look for this field.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-confirmed [edit]: and confirm_password should be renamed to password_confirmation as well